# using ubuntu-server in full screen mode - VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-10.10, xorg, fullscreen

I have installed ubuntu-server 11.10 in virtual box. but unfortunately the screen is small. I installed VirtualBox guest additions to see it full screen(like what I do for windows). Now it is installed and its services are running but I still don't get full screen. There is not GUI. I just installed xorg. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VirtualBox Guest Additions are works for graphical interface, not for text interface...

If you set console frame buffer in grub conf you might have full screen virtual ubuntu server. [Take a look at this link for more information..](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=41881)

IMO connecting with ssh to virtual machine is safer than changing frame buffer settings in grub. You can change ssh window height & width as you wish. And nothing is different with real terminal.

Answer (score 7):

You can have the ubuntu server console in VirtualBox start at a resolution that your graphic card supports via the virtualbox environment.

### Quick Steps (**[Source](http://www.aahank.com/2012/11/change-ubuntu-server-terminal-cli.html)**)

- Check the resolutions your graphic card supports via the VirtualBox Environment (VBE).You should be able to find that out by issuing the command '`vbeinfo`' in the GRUB console (hit the <kbd>C</kbd> key when the GRUB boot menu shows up).
- Pick one resolution, then open '/etc/default/grub' (e.g. `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`) and change the line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` to something like this `GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864` (where 1152x864 should be your custom resolution which is also supported by your graphic card).
- Now run these two commands one-by-one:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  sudo reboot
  ```

You should now see your VM's console in the custom resolution that you just set.

(**PS:** As Javier Rivera said, full screen resolution may not be possible.)

Answer (score 1):

I might try the `sudo apt-get install xrdp`

and

Next, go to Start –> All Programs –> Accessories –> Remote Desktop Connection from your Windows computer and type the IP address or Hostname of the Ubuntu machine then click ‘Connect’

And, use your Ubuntu username and password.

Or, install `kde-desktop` package on ubuntu server

on VirtualBox menu - "Devices > Enable remote desktop display"